# MDX ALL Level of every attribute in a dimension

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssas, mdx

I am trying to create a measure in my cube, SSAS 2008 R2.

I have a Product dimension with 10 attributes and 5 hierarchies, which I don't think is unusual.

Product
-Size
-Exclusive To
-PriceCode
-Category
-Range
etc...

I have a measure CustomerCount that I wish to see for the ALL level across "Product" as a total.  I also have other dimensions with multiple attributes and hierarchies, where I wish to maintain the user selections, so for example Country "USA", Account Type "National", Month "May 2012" etc...

I currently have

```
Measures.TotCustomerCount = ([Measures].[CustomerCount],[Product].[Size].[All],[Product].[Exclusive To].[All],[Product].[PriceCode].[All],[Product].[Category].[All],[Product].[Range].[All],... )
```

This works... however it's laborious, and if any new attributes are created or indeed removed I need to update this statement.  Surely there is a better way.

Is there something that will allow

```
Measures.TotCustomerCount = ([Measures].[CustomerCount],[Product].TopLevels? )
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to only include the key attribute and `.AllMembers` here, so something like:

`Measures.TotCustomerCount = (Measures.CustomerCount,Product.Product.AllMembers)` where Product is the Attribute (Lowest Level) for the Product dimension.

Comment: thanks for your answer, when I saw it, I thought of course!, but I still can't get it working.  I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Root( Dimension ) will give you the All member (or default member) for each attribute

```
Measures.TotCustomerCount = ([Measures].[CustomerCount],Root([Product]))
```